# Execute a program with a sequential list of files

Tags: macos, unix, terminal.app

I have a list of files with titles like the following:

```
file_0.10_180.0degrees.txt
file_0.15_180.0degrees.txt
file_0.20_180.0degrees.txt
file_0.25_180.0degrees.txt
```

where the files can be passed in as command-line arguments. I want to pass in all of those files without typing in all of them one by one.

So far, I have tried

```
./example file_0.{10..25..5}*
```

and

```
./example file_0.$(seq 10 5 25)*
```

Both of which had failed. I tried to find out why they failed and see the following:

```
>echo file_0.{10..25..5}*
>file_0.{10..25..5}*
>echo file_0.$(seq 10 5 25)*
>file_0.10 15 20 25*
```

Comment: What is the shell you're using?

Comment: The version of bash that comes with macOS (v3.2.57) doesn't support intervals in brace expansions (they appear to have been added in v4.0). That is, `{10..25}` will expand, but `{10..25..5}` won't.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am using bash shell.